# Android Kotlin: Callback method inside Activity by separeted class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have created a class called **HttpRequests.kt**, Where it stores a simple method responsible for making requests on the internet:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class HttpRequests() {

    fun doARequest(context: Context){
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val url = "https://www.google.com"

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                //How I can call a method inside ConfigActivity file, sending the variable 'response'?
            },
            { error -> Log.d("http","[ERROR]: $error") })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `Volley library` to send and receive requests.

This method (`doARequest`) is called once my **ConfigActivity.kt** screen is created by the `onCreate()` method:

```
class ConfigActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        //Handle Request
        val requests: HttpRequests = HttpRequests()
        requests.doARequest(this)
    }
}
```

This code works like a charm. As we know the return methods of the `Volley library` are **asynchronous**, in this case, the execution of the code is not affected by the request.

Knowing this, how can I call a **callback** within the `StringRequest response`, in order to execute an existing method within my `ConfigActivity`?

> For example: When the request return, I need to call a method that
> exists inside ConfigActivity, where this method will be responsible
> for sending the user to the next screen.

Comment: A class that doesn’t hold any state in properties or implement any interfaces doesn’t need to be a class at all. It’s really weird to need to instantiate a class just to call what could be a static function. However, it would make sense if it implemented an interface and was injected into your activity using dependency injection. Then the implementation can be swapped out for testing.

Comment: Note that instead of using a callback in an activity, you usually would want to make calls like this in a ViewModel and set the result in a LiveData or SharedFlow that the Activity is observing. This way, the request doesn’t have to be restarted from scratch each time the Activity is recreated, such as after a screen rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
fun doARequest(context: Context, onResponse:(response: YourType) -> Unit){
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
val url = "https://www.google.com"

val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    onResponse,
    { error -> Log.d("http","[ERROR]: $error") })

queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```